# Link next to each row in sql table result in php to display full data for that row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to display couple of fields from sql table and want to add a link in each row that takes user to a page that shows all results for that specific table row.

Let me explain more: I have a MySql table that has the following fields: filename, intro_data, content_data, conclusion_data. I have created a php page that displays the list of all data for the filenames & intro_data fields in that sql table using this code:

```
//Query to select rows or data in table
$query= "SELECT filename,intro_data FROM file_data";  
$result=mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if (!$result)  
{  
  die('Error fetching results: ' . mysqli_error()); 
  exit();  
}

echo '<table border="1">'; // start a table tag in the HTML
//Storing the results in an Array
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  //Creates a loop to loop through results
{  
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['filename'] . '</td><td>' . $row['intro_data'] . '</td><td> <a href="full_table_row_results.php">More Info</a></td></tr>';  
}  
echo '</table>'; //Close the table in HTML

//Closing DB Connection
mysqli_close($connect);
```

If you noticed in the above code, I have a "More Info" anchor tag that links to 'full_table_row_results.php'. In this page, I want it to show all the field results (filename, intro_data, content_data, conclusion_data) for that particular row. I know that I can query all results for a table like this:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM file_data";
```

But how can I create the 'full_table_row_results.php' that queries all fields for that particular row that the user is clicking on? Since the row results are from an array, how do I know which row number in that array has the user clicked on? I am not sure how to code the More Info page.

I am stuck on this and not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution (as always, there's many other).

First, you need an `id` for each row in your table (if you do not have already one). With MySQL an auto_increment integer field does the job.
Next, you need to get the `id` in your php code.

```
$query= "SELECT id, filename,intro_data FROM file_data";
```

Then you use it as a parameter when you link to your full_table_row_results.php script. The link will be:

```
echo '<a href="full_table_row_results.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">' /* etc. */ ;
```

(Adapt it in your code, I did not copy all your code to easier readability).
And in this last script you get access to this parameter with $_GET['id']. Then you can query your database for this one row only (with a WHERE clause).

Hope this help

Comment: id seems like a good idea and then passing it through to php file should work I guess. I didnt create an id field in mysql table yet. I will create it now. I am assuming, if I am only displaying the results created by a particular user only (by matching the username field in table with that logged in user), I am guessing the sql id for those row shouldnt change (unlike array value) since its auto-incremented to all value added to that table. I will add the id field now and give it a try. Thank you so much Armage. I will post back once I have tested it out. :)

Comment: I just created the id field with int, not null, auto-increment settings and it worked! PERFECT! I was then able to pass through to the php file and fetch the results for that id in that second page. Thank you so much.. I was stuck on it and your suggestion worked like a charm and was also easy to implement. Cheers!